# Prove or disprove the statement: There exists a set T such that for all sets S, (S ⋂ T = ∅)

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

I need help proving or disproving this statement.

For the negation of the statement I got:

For every set T, there exists a set S, where (S ⋂ T ≠ ∅). Is this negation correct?

Can someone please help me prove or disprove this statement? I'm really confused.

Comment: Correct. Way to go!

Answer (score 1):

You correctly negated the statement. However, it is relatively easier to prove the original statement. Just consider $T = \emptyset$.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Your negation is correct. And what does it tell you when you take $T=\varnothing$?

Comment: How do we know that T is an empty set? Where, and how should I start?

Comment: @Jake: I did not say that $T$ was the empty set. Look again at your negation: *for every set* $T$ *there exists a set* $S$ *such that* $S\cap T\ne\varnothing$. Is that true? That’s a statement about **all** sets $T$. $\varnothing$ is a possible value of $T$. Is it true that there is a set $S$ such that $S\cap\varnothing\ne\varnothing$?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way is to calculate for which $\;T\;$ the statement in question holds, by expanding the definitions from the set-level to the element-level, and using predicate logic to simplify:
\begin{align}
& \langle \forall S :: S \cap T = \varnothing \rangle \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"basic property of $\;\varnothing\;$; definition of $\;\cap\;$"} \\
& \langle \forall S :: \langle \forall x :: \lnot(x \in S \land x \in T \rangle \rangle \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"logic: DeMorgan"} \\
& \langle \forall S :: \langle \forall x :: x \not\in S \lor x \not\in T \rangle \rangle \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"logic: move $\;\forall S\;$ to the only place where it is used"} \\
& \langle \forall x :: \langle \forall S :: x \not\in S \rangle \lor x \not\in T \rangle \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"$\;\langle \forall S :: x \not\in S \rangle\;$ is false: take $\;S := \{x\}\;$"} \\
& \langle \forall x :: \text{false} \lor x \not\in T \rangle \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"logic: simplify"} \\
& \langle \forall x :: x \not\in T \rangle \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"basic property of $\;\varnothing\;$"} \\
& T = \varnothing \\
\end{align}
From this you can directly answer your original question.